# After removing user, emails to another user receive bounce-backs

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, email-bounces

We have two domains.  Our primary, abeeceedee.com, and abcd.com, which is set up as a "User alias domain for abeeceedee.com"

My Google Domain administrator removed angie@abeeceedee.com and now when ANYBODY sends an email to jack@abeeceedee.com they get a bounce-back that says:

```
Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to angie@abcd.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.
LEARN MORE
The response was:
550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser q25sor14896966edi.26 - gsmtp

Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns; me@mydomain.com
Arrival-Date: Mon, 30 Aug 2021 09:10:51 -0700 (PDT)
X-Original-Message-ID: <47530f4f-01f8-43a0-aecc-2832a8225dee@www.myprovider.com>

Final-Recipient: rfc822; angie@abcd.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser q25sor14896966edi.26 - gsmtp
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 30 Aug 2021 09:10:52 -0700 (PDT)

From: "Me" <me@mydomain.com>
Subject: Re: weird angie rejection
Date: August 30, 2021 at 12:10:27 PM EDT
To: "User Sam" <sam@abeeceedee.com>
Cc: "User Jack" <jack@abeeceedee.com>
```

I checked user Jack's account settings and there are no forwards or rules set up.  There are no groups or rules that I have been able to find that links user Jack's account with the one that was deleted.  Any hints on what else I can check?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. You should report this issue to your domain administrator.

Comment: The admin asked me for help and I have access to anything I need.  I have managed DNS and e-mail before for a hosting provider (hundreds of businesses, thousands of accounts) but not so much in Google Workspace.  There are no complex configurations set up for this domain - no aliases, no groups, etc. Seems like something on the backend is busted.  I'll try to get help from GMail.

Comment: I recreated user angie@ and the bounce backs (when emailing user jack@) stopped.  I removed the angie@ account and the bounce backs start again.  I added "angie" as an alias to the domain admin's account and the bounce backs (when emailing user jack@) have stopped.  I'm leaving the alias in place because it's not worth my time trying to get Gmail support to understand and fix the issue.  (One thing I like about Fastmail.com is their super responsive and helpful support.)

Answer (score 0):

### Review the Email Logs

The email logs for the offending message(s) will provide insight.  They are found in Reporting > Email Log Search [(admin.google.com/u/0/ac/emaillogsearch)](https://admin.google.com/u/0/ac/emaillogsearch/details)
In the details you will see info such as 'Matched rules'.

### Check Additional Places for Custom Delivery Rules

In the Google Admin navigate to  Apps > Google Workspace > Gmail

You should review the following areas for a custom rule that exists outside the user's account:

1. Default Routing
2. Compliance
3. Routing